# hide svg affect its twin

Tags: html, css, svg

I have two similar SVGs (twins) in my HTML, when I hide first one some parts of the second also disappear why is that? I use id and CSS display property to hide the SVG, I've tried visibility property and also the same result or worse (hide more parts)

- SVG has many details inside of it

**normal SVGs:**
[image]

**using display property:**

```
display: none;
```

[image]

**using visibility property:**

```
visibility: hidden;
```

[image]

**SVG file:**

```css
#C{
display:none;
```

```html
<svg id="C" width="427" height="128" viewBox="0 0 427 128" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M25 4H412L427 128H10L25 4Z" fill="#D6F4FA"/>
<path d="M10.5682 120.5L25.44 4.50009H411.56L426.432 120.5H10.5682Z" fill="#E8FBFF" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#E8FBFF"/>
<g opacity="0.6" filter="url(#filter0_f_208_1612)">
<mask id="mask0_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="4" width="417" height="117">
<path d="M0.568195 120.5L15.44 4.50009H401.56L416.432 120.5H0.568195Z" fill="#F9FEFF" stroke="#EDFCFF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0_208_1612)">
<path d="M212.503 -71.2604L276.966 -30.9579L140.239 163.741L75.7754 123.439L212.503 -71.2604Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
<g opacity="0.6" filter="url(#filter1_f_208_1612)">
<mask id="mask1_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="137" y="4" width="280" height="117">
<path d="M137.545 120.5L147.531 4.50009H406.469L416.455 120.5H137.545Z" fill="#F9FEFF" stroke="#EDFCFF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask1_208_1612)">
<path d="M349.503 -71.2604L374.202 -55.8186L237.474 138.881L212.775 123.439L349.503 -71.2604Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
<path d="M113 58.8572C113 74.2422 95.7466 86.7143 78.7589 86.7143C61.7712 86.7143 48 80.407 48 58.8572C48 43.4721 61.7712 31 78.7589 31C101.393 31 113 43.4721 113 58.8572Z" fill="#D5FAFF"/>
<mask id="mask2_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="48" y="31" width="65" height="56">
<path d="M113 58.8572C113 74.2422 95.7466 86.7143 78.7589 86.7143C61.7712 86.7143 48 80.407 48 58.8572C48 43.4721 61.7712 31 78.7589 31C101.393 31 113 43.4721 113 58.8572Z" fill="#D5FAFF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask2_208_1612)">
<g filter="url(#filter2_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M108.011 59.3828C115.284 75.3691 94.7341 86.7143 78.3565 86.7143C61.9789 86.7143 44.2261 75.3691 48.7023 59.3828C53.1784 43.3964 61.9789 32.0512 78.3565 32.0512C94.7341 32.0512 104.094 44.4278 108.011 59.3828Z" fill="#A25A5A"/>
</g>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter3_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M94.4285 58.8572C94.4285 66.6948 87.413 73.0485 78.7589 73.0485C70.1048 73.0485 59.0267 70.9461 63.0892 58.8572C63.0892 51.0195 70.1048 39.4097 78.7589 39.4097C90.366 39.4097 94.4285 51.0195 94.4285 58.8572Z" fill="#B30101"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter4_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M96.75 48.9911C96.75 55.081 88.955 43.7679 79.3393 43.7679C69.7236 43.7679 61.9286 55.081 61.9286 48.9911C61.9286 42.9012 69.7236 37.9643 79.3393 37.9643C88.955 37.9643 96.75 42.9012 96.75 48.9911Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<path d="M248.07 48.4563C256.54 67.1269 225.094 74.8907 210.434 85.0578C191.363 85.0578 185.898 74.2129 175.904 53.137C167.6 35.628 197.914 32.1889 216.984 32.1889C236.055 32.1889 237.934 36.9336 248.07 48.4563Z" fill="#FFF7CF"/>
<mask id="mask3_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="174" y="32" width="76" height="54">
<path d="M248.07 48.4563C256.54 67.1269 225.094 74.8907 210.434 85.0578C191.363 85.0578 185.898 74.2129 175.904 53.137C167.6 35.628 197.914 32.1889 216.984 32.1889C236.055 32.1889 237.934 36.9336 248.07 48.4563Z" fill="#FFF7CF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask3_208_1612)">
<g filter="url(#filter5_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M243.33 49.7524C250.742 66.0428 223.223 72.8168 210.394 81.6877C193.705 81.6877 188.922 72.2254 180.175 53.8364C172.909 38.5595 199.437 35.5589 216.126 35.5589C232.815 35.5589 234.459 39.6987 243.33 49.7524Z" fill="#F9983E"/>
</g>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter6_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M221.979 57.4359C230.16 66.1739 219.377 73.9922 211.751 73.9922C204.126 73.9922 183.626 60.1172 187.206 50.5374C187.206 44.3265 200.546 42.025 208.172 42.025C218.399 42.025 213.797 52.377 221.979 57.4359Z" fill="#F83207"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter7_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M232.858 56.4883C230.473 62.4822 225.148 54.3968 215.684 50.6315C206.22 46.8662 196.201 48.8469 198.585 42.8529C200.97 36.859 210.575 35.0524 220.039 38.8177C229.503 42.583 235.242 50.4944 232.858 56.4883Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<path d="M364.378 62.2292C357.768 80.9583 349.053 90 330.149 90C311.245 90 310.774 77.9043 310.774 59C310.774 40.0958 311.245 28 330.149 28C349.053 28 372.128 40.2708 364.378 62.2292Z" fill="#E7E7E7"/>
<mask id="mask4_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="310" y="28" width="56" height="62">
<path d="M364.378 62.2292C357.768 80.9583 349.053 90 330.149 90C311.245 90 310.774 77.9043 310.774 59C310.774 40.0958 311.245 28 330.149 28C349.053 28 372.128 40.2708 364.378 62.2292Z" fill="#F0F0F0"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask4_208_1612)">
<g filter="url(#filter8_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M359.858 60.9563C352.893 78.375 351.127 84.8334 332.087 84.8334C313.046 84.8334 316.447 80.6482 316.447 60.9563C316.447 41.2644 313.046 31.8938 332.087 31.8938C346.295 31.8938 367.729 41.2677 359.858 60.9563Z" fill="#F93E3E"/>
</g>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter9_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M356.628 60.4784C356.628 69.3955 350.816 67.5307 340.483 76.6242C333.378 82.876 317.878 63.0099 324.337 60.4784C340.483 62.3641 331.565 44.3325 340.483 44.3325C349.4 44.3325 356.628 51.5613 356.628 60.4784Z" fill="#B50404"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter10_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M350.816 46.4819C348.311 52.7788 349.779 47.9613 339.837 44.0056C329.894 40.0499 328.936 42.5525 331.441 36.2556C337.755 34.0708 337.755 36.2556 342.331 34.0708C352.273 38.0265 353.321 40.185 350.816 46.4819Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_f_208_1612" x="71.7754" y="9.15527e-05" width="209.191" height="125" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter1_f_208_1612" x="208.775" y="9.15527e-05" width="169.426" height="125" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter2_f_208_1612" x="38" y="22.0512" width="81.5178" height="74.6631" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter3_f_208_1612" x="52.2234" y="29.4097" width="52.2051" height="53.6388" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter4_f_208_1612" x="57.9286" y="33.9643" width="42.8214" height="20.8271" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter5_f_208_1612" x="168.943" y="25.5589" width="85.6344" height="66.1288" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter6_f_208_1612" x="176.79" y="32.025" width="58.1147" height="51.9672" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter7_f_208_1612" x="194.229" y="32.8523" width="43.1686" height="29.7799" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter8_f_208_1612" x="312.211" y="27.8938" width="53.334" height="60.9395" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter9_f_208_1612" x="312.797" y="34.3325" width="53.8315" height="53.5025" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter10_f_208_1612" x="326.27" y="30.0708" width="29.6991" height="23.4518" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>

<svg  width="427" height="128" viewBox="0 0 427 128" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M25 4H412L427 128H10L25 4Z" fill="#D6F4FA"/>
<path d="M10.5682 120.5L25.44 4.50009H411.56L426.432 120.5H10.5682Z" fill="#E8FBFF" fill-opacity="0.5" stroke="#E8FBFF"/>
<g opacity="0.6" filter="url(#filter0_f_208_1612)">
<mask id="mask0_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="0" y="4" width="417" height="117">
<path d="M0.568195 120.5L15.44 4.50009H401.56L416.432 120.5H0.568195Z" fill="#F9FEFF" stroke="#EDFCFF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask0_208_1612)">
<path d="M212.503 -71.2604L276.966 -30.9579L140.239 163.741L75.7754 123.439L212.503 -71.2604Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
<g opacity="0.6" filter="url(#filter1_f_208_1612)">
<mask id="mask1_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="137" y="4" width="280" height="117">
<path d="M137.545 120.5L147.531 4.50009H406.469L416.455 120.5H137.545Z" fill="#F9FEFF" stroke="#EDFCFF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask1_208_1612)">
<path d="M349.503 -71.2604L374.202 -55.8186L237.474 138.881L212.775 123.439L349.503 -71.2604Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
</g>
<path d="M113 58.8572C113 74.2422 95.7466 86.7143 78.7589 86.7143C61.7712 86.7143 48 80.407 48 58.8572C48 43.4721 61.7712 31 78.7589 31C101.393 31 113 43.4721 113 58.8572Z" fill="#D5FAFF"/>
<mask id="mask2_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="48" y="31" width="65" height="56">
<path d="M113 58.8572C113 74.2422 95.7466 86.7143 78.7589 86.7143C61.7712 86.7143 48 80.407 48 58.8572C48 43.4721 61.7712 31 78.7589 31C101.393 31 113 43.4721 113 58.8572Z" fill="#D5FAFF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask2_208_1612)">
<g filter="url(#filter2_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M108.011 59.3828C115.284 75.3691 94.7341 86.7143 78.3565 86.7143C61.9789 86.7143 44.2261 75.3691 48.7023 59.3828C53.1784 43.3964 61.9789 32.0512 78.3565 32.0512C94.7341 32.0512 104.094 44.4278 108.011 59.3828Z" fill="#A25A5A"/>
</g>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter3_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M94.4285 58.8572C94.4285 66.6948 87.413 73.0485 78.7589 73.0485C70.1048 73.0485 59.0267 70.9461 63.0892 58.8572C63.0892 51.0195 70.1048 39.4097 78.7589 39.4097C90.366 39.4097 94.4285 51.0195 94.4285 58.8572Z" fill="#B30101"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter4_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M96.75 48.9911C96.75 55.081 88.955 43.7679 79.3393 43.7679C69.7236 43.7679 61.9286 55.081 61.9286 48.9911C61.9286 42.9012 69.7236 37.9643 79.3393 37.9643C88.955 37.9643 96.75 42.9012 96.75 48.9911Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<path d="M248.07 48.4563C256.54 67.1269 225.094 74.8907 210.434 85.0578C191.363 85.0578 185.898 74.2129 175.904 53.137C167.6 35.628 197.914 32.1889 216.984 32.1889C236.055 32.1889 237.934 36.9336 248.07 48.4563Z" fill="#FFF7CF"/>
<mask id="mask3_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="174" y="32" width="76" height="54">
<path d="M248.07 48.4563C256.54 67.1269 225.094 74.8907 210.434 85.0578C191.363 85.0578 185.898 74.2129 175.904 53.137C167.6 35.628 197.914 32.1889 216.984 32.1889C236.055 32.1889 237.934 36.9336 248.07 48.4563Z" fill="#FFF7CF"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask3_208_1612)">
<g filter="url(#filter5_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M243.33 49.7524C250.742 66.0428 223.223 72.8168 210.394 81.6877C193.705 81.6877 188.922 72.2254 180.175 53.8364C172.909 38.5595 199.437 35.5589 216.126 35.5589C232.815 35.5589 234.459 39.6987 243.33 49.7524Z" fill="#F9983E"/>
</g>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter6_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M221.979 57.4359C230.16 66.1739 219.377 73.9922 211.751 73.9922C204.126 73.9922 183.626 60.1172 187.206 50.5374C187.206 44.3265 200.546 42.025 208.172 42.025C218.399 42.025 213.797 52.377 221.979 57.4359Z" fill="#F83207"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter7_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M232.858 56.4883C230.473 62.4822 225.148 54.3968 215.684 50.6315C206.22 46.8662 196.201 48.8469 198.585 42.8529C200.97 36.859 210.575 35.0524 220.039 38.8177C229.503 42.583 235.242 50.4944 232.858 56.4883Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<path d="M364.378 62.2292C357.768 80.9583 349.053 90 330.149 90C311.245 90 310.774 77.9043 310.774 59C310.774 40.0958 311.245 28 330.149 28C349.053 28 372.128 40.2708 364.378 62.2292Z" fill="#E7E7E7"/>
<mask id="mask4_208_1612" style="mask-type:alpha" maskUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x="310" y="28" width="56" height="62">
<path d="M364.378 62.2292C357.768 80.9583 349.053 90 330.149 90C311.245 90 310.774 77.9043 310.774 59C310.774 40.0958 311.245 28 330.149 28C349.053 28 372.128 40.2708 364.378 62.2292Z" fill="#F0F0F0"/>
</mask>
<g mask="url(#mask4_208_1612)">
<g filter="url(#filter8_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M359.858 60.9563C352.893 78.375 351.127 84.8334 332.087 84.8334C313.046 84.8334 316.447 80.6482 316.447 60.9563C316.447 41.2644 313.046 31.8938 332.087 31.8938C346.295 31.8938 367.729 41.2677 359.858 60.9563Z" fill="#F93E3E"/>
</g>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter9_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M356.628 60.4784C356.628 69.3955 350.816 67.5307 340.483 76.6242C333.378 82.876 317.878 63.0099 324.337 60.4784C340.483 62.3641 331.565 44.3325 340.483 44.3325C349.4 44.3325 356.628 51.5613 356.628 60.4784Z" fill="#B50404"/>
</g>
<g filter="url(#filter10_f_208_1612)">
<path d="M350.816 46.4819C348.311 52.7788 349.779 47.9613 339.837 44.0056C329.894 40.0499 328.936 42.5525 331.441 36.2556C337.755 34.0708 337.755 36.2556 342.331 34.0708C352.273 38.0265 353.321 40.185 350.816 46.4819Z" fill="white"/>
</g>
<defs>
<filter id="filter0_f_208_1612" x="71.7754" y="9.15527e-05" width="209.191" height="125" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter1_f_208_1612" x="208.775" y="9.15527e-05" width="169.426" height="125" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter2_f_208_1612" x="38" y="22.0512" width="81.5178" height="74.6631" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter3_f_208_1612" x="52.2234" y="29.4097" width="52.2051" height="53.6388" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter4_f_208_1612" x="57.9286" y="33.9643" width="42.8214" height="20.8271" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter5_f_208_1612" x="168.943" y="25.5589" width="85.6344" height="66.1288" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter6_f_208_1612" x="176.79" y="32.025" width="58.1147" height="51.9672" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter7_f_208_1612" x="194.229" y="32.8523" width="43.1686" height="29.7799" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter8_f_208_1612" x="312.211" y="27.8938" width="53.334" height="60.9395" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter9_f_208_1612" x="312.797" y="34.3325" width="53.8315" height="53.5025" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
<filter id="filter10_f_208_1612" x="326.27" y="30.0708" width="29.6991" height="23.4518" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
<feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
<feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" result="effect1_foregroundBlur_208_1612"/>
</filter>
</defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: Duplicate id values are invalid. Make them all unique.

Comment: @RobertLongson - thank you that's right. I've tried it, changed all ids and it worked. Is there a way to make `filter="url(#filter4_f_208_1612)"` (for example) targets this svg id only not other id with the same name?

Comment: You can define the filters etc. that you need in a separate SVG and then refer to the "shared" filters from all your SVGs.

Comment: You don't need to have the filters twice. You can put all the filters in the first svg element or even in a third svg element with width="0" height="0"